# About ASP.NET page rendering when CSS is applied

Tags: asp.net, css

If I have a label on my asp.net page with ForeColor property set to "DarkBlue".
Also i hae applied a CSS to the same label in which Color is mentioned as "Red".

When the page gets renderd, text in the label will be in which color "DarkBlue" or "Red"
and why??

Comment: the best thing to do is go try it.. its not difficult to test..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based on CSS rules, inline styling will have priority over stylesheet includes. So it will actually render as "DarkBlue".